# REST API: InputStream Copying (dovetailing) Failing for Big Files

Tags: java, rest, inputstream

Using Jersey 1.8, I am developing a REST API to upload files. In turn, I am using a service providers REST API to upload the files to their site. The flow looks like:

Browser --> My REST using Jersey server side; and then using Apache HTTP Client to make onward REST calls --> Service Provider's REST.

When I upload small files (<1MB), it all works fine. But when the file size increases it gives me following error.

```
A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at character 0
```

I suspect the error is due to the stream getting "cut" the mid-way. What is the issue with the following code snippet (I have removed the irrelevant code).

```
@POST
@Path("/upload")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response uploadDocument(@FormDataParam("document") InputStream inputStream) {
        FilenetAdapter filenet = new FilenetAdapter();
        String documentId = filenet.uploadDocument(inputStream);
        // return the Jersey call - code removed for bravity
}

//FilenetAdapert.uploadDocument function
public String uploadDocument(InputStream inputStream) {

    HttpPost request = new HttpPost(serviceUrl);
    request.setEntity(buildMultipartEntity(metadata, inputStream));

    CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
    CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
    //consume the response - code removed for bravity
}

private HttpEntity buildMultipartEntity(JSONObject metadata, InputStream inputStream)
        throws IOException, URISyntaxException, JSONException {

    // Build a multipart HTTP request according to RFC1341
    MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();

    // Set request metadata
    StringBody stringBody = new StringBody(metadata.toString(), ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN);
    FormBodyPartBuilder bodyPartBuilder = FormBodyPartBuilder.create();
    bodyPartBuilder.setName("metadata");
    bodyPartBuilder.setBody(stringBody);
    FormBodyPart mdata = bodyPartBuilder.build();
    builder.addPart(mdata);

    // Set request content
    ContentBody cbFile = new InputStreamBody(inputStream, ContentType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);
    builder.addPart("file", cbFile);
    return builder.build();
}
```

Comment: Please ignore the fact that I am using Jersey for server side rest and Apache HTTPClient for client side calls. I will amend it when I have time. Probably I will use Jersey for both.

Comment: Exceeding max post data size? Where is the exception coming from? While uploading data from client to your own server or uploading data from your sever to Service Provider's REST.

Comment: While uploading data from my sever to Service Provider's REST

Comment: @David, I did some research on your suggestion - max post data size - looks like it is configured on the server and not as a part of POST request. Am I right?

Comment: Looks like the max limit is 2MB - consistent with what is mentioned in various threads. Also looks like this is something the Service Provider will have to change on their server. I have requested them so. Will update you all on the outcome. Thanks!

Comment: Yep, it is server side configuration ;D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The service provider changed their server configuration. That resolved the issue.